# Multiple Update Statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can we perform multiple `Update` Statement in `SQL Server`

. I have tried with but SQL Server error is occurred.

**Error**

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

**The example is**

```
UPDATE FACULTY SET Salary=(
12000 WHERE Faculty_ID=0163,
8,500 WHERE Faculty_ID=0164,
14,500 WHERE Faculty_ID=0165,
10,000 WHERE Faculty_ID=0166
);
```

Comment: Error message is `ORA` => `Oracle`. Then statement is for `SQL Server` and  question is tagged as `MySQL`. These are completely different RDBMS. You should be aware name of your DB.

Comment: @lad2025 Sorry for this, and thank you for correcting my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement's

```
UPDATE FACULTY
SET    Salary = CASE
                  WHEN Faculty_ID = '0163' THEN 12000
                  WHEN Faculty_ID = '0164' THEN 8500
                  WHEN Faculty_ID = '0165' THEN 14500
                  WHEN Faculty_ID = '0166' THEN 10000
                END
WHERE  Faculty_ID IN ( '0163', '0164', '0165', '0166' )
```

Considering you don't want to update other `Faculty_ID's`

Comment: Probably `Faculty_ID` like  `0163` or `0164` are strings, otherwise there is no point of leading `0`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just writing four update statements:

```
UPDATE FACULTY SET Salary = 12000 WHERE Faculty_ID = 0163;
UPDATE FACULTY SET Salary = 8500 WHERE Faculty_ID = 0164;
UPDATE FACULTY SET Salary = 14500 WHERE Faculty_ID = 0165;
UPDATE FACULTY SET Salary = 10000 WHERE Faculty_ID = 0166;
```

Although you can do this in one statement, the logic is more complicated, prone to error, and harder to maintain.  With an index on `Faculty_ID` the overhead for four queries should be pretty small.

Note about numbers and strings.  SQL does not recognize commas as a separator within a number, so don't use that.  Also, the leading zero in the id is unnecessary for a number.  If `Faculty_ID` is a string, then use single quotes.